# Calling async method on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, windows-phone-8, asynchronous

I created Windows Phone 8.1 project and I am trying to run `async` method `GetResponse<T>(string url)` on button click and waiting for the method to finish, but method is never finishing. Here is my code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs 
{
      Task<List<MyObject>> task = GetResponse<MyObject>("my url");
      task.Wait();
      var items = task.Result; //break point here
}

public static async Task<List<T>> GetResponse<T>(string url)
{
    List<T> items = null;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
    try
    {
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string text = strReader.ReadToEnd();
        items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(text);
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return items;
}
```

It will hang on `task.Wait()`.

I changed my button click method to `async` and used `await` before the `async` method and I get the result(`await GetResponse<string>("url")`). What is wrong with `Task<List<string>> task = GetResponse<string>("url")`?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a small note, it is a general convention that `async` methods are suffixed with `Async`, i.e. your method name would be `GetResponseAsync`.

Comment: Calling `task.Wait();` is redundant here. `task.Result` will already call `task.Wait()` when necessary.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You're the victim of the classic deadlock. `task.Wait()` or `task.Result` is a blocking call in UI thread which causes the deadlock.

[Don't block in the UI thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Never do it. Just `await` it.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs 
{
      var task = GetResponseAsync<MyObject>("my url");
      var items = await task;
}
```

Btw, why are you catching the `WebException` and throwing it back? It would be better if you simply don't catch it. Both are same.

Also I can see you're mixing the asynchronous code with synchronous code inside the `GetResponse` method. `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` is a blocking call --you should be using `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync`.

Also use "Async" suffix to methods which returns a Task or asynchronous to follow the TAP("Task based Asynchronous Pattern") convention as [Jon says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28601720/2530848).

Your method should look something like the following when you've addressed all the above concerns.

```
public static async Task<List<T>> GetResponseAsync<T>(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string text = await strReader.ReadToEndAsync();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(text);
}
```

Answer (score 36):

This is what's killing you:

```
task.Wait();
```

That's blocking the UI thread until the task has completed - but the task is an async method which is going to try to get back to the UI thread after it "pauses" and awaits an async result. It can't do that, because you're blocking the UI thread...

There's nothing in your code which really looks like it needs to be on the UI thread anyway, but assuming you really *do* want it there, you should use:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs 
{
    Task<List<MyObject>> task = GetResponse<MyObject>("my url");
    var items = await task;
    // Presumably use items here
}
```

Or just:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs 
{
    var items = await GetResponse<MyObject>("my url");
    // Presumably use items here
}
```

Now instead of *blocking* until the task has completed, the `Button_Click` method will return after scheduling a continuation to fire when the task has completed. (That's how async/await works, basically.)

Note that I would also rename `GetResponse` to `GetResponseAsync` for clarity.

Comment: I've added `async` to my button click event handler and am `await`ing the async task but the async task is still running on my main thread and blocking the Windows Form UI.  Any ideas why when I'm following the above example? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: Yes, the async task *would* still run on your main thread. If it's truly asynchronous (e.g. doing asynchronous IO) that should be fine. It's *not* fine if that task performs blocking operations. I suggest you ask a new question with a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisWalsh: If you use Task.Run() and call the async task inside that function, the task will run on a new UI thread and prevent blocking your UI.

Answer (score -4):

use below code

```
 Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(async () => await GetResponse<MyObject>("my url")));
```

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` will block in the same way as `task.Wait`.

Comment: question was "button click and waiting for the method to finish" so above code snip will wait until method to finish.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed.. THank you. I have a user clicking a button.. that button does different things... one of which MAY end up needing to call an Asyc Process. Needed to know how to halt.. allow that process to finish, so my current thread can continue on to the next step. Works perfect!